# C# formclosing event and loops

Tags: c#, loops

If I have to declare a little bit more please tell me, it's a little bit late here.

I have a little problem, this code keeps looping :(...

I have this

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Confirm Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Stop();
    _exited = true;

    foreach (Process x in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        while (x.Id == _processID)
        {
            Application.Exit();
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code trying to accomplish?  What is _processID?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This code is just really wrong. Why would you need to loop an `Application.Exit` call?

Comment: `while (x.Id == _processID)`  ummh why not `if (x.Id == _processID)` ? Agree with the other comments though - this code should not exist in the first place.

Comment: I suspect `x.Id == _processID`

Comment: _processID is the ID of the process that's being made in the program somehwere. So I want to capture this ID, which isn't that hard. But upon closing I want to warn the user if the process is still running. Sorry for my English :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

It keeps looping because you call `Application.Exit()` inside this method. I dont know what you trying to do but i think you want to ask the user if he really wants close the app.
If your set `e.Cancel = true`it means you cancel the event, so in your case you cancel to close the app.

So if your ask "sure you want to quit" and user choose "No" you should set `e.Cancel = true`, if not do nothing because the default value of `e.Cancel` is `false`.

#### Sample

```
// create a list of process
private List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();

// if you start a process
Process myProcess = //;
processes.Add(myProcess);

// on closing
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var isAProcessRunning = processes.Where(p => p.HasExited == false);

    if (isAProcessRunning.Any()) 
    {
      // some process is already running, ask the user 

        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Confirm Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) ==
        DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Form.FormClosing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: There's process being made in the program and I want to warn the user if the process is still running if they close the form, but the messagebox keeps popping up :(.

Comment: Sorry, but i need more information. How you start the processes ?

Comment: I create a new process with Process process1 = new Process();. But I want to make a warning message upon close.

Comment: @Darkshadw i hope i understand your sceneario ;) Check out my updated answer. I am really sure we can solve your problem.

Comment: Exiting the problem does not kill the processes you already created, do you want to kill the processes ?

Comment: Well, I want to check if it's still running, not exually killing it because the process writes data to a file and if I kill it... Yeah, you already guessed it, it might corrupt the data ;).

Comment: Ok ;) we are near to the solution. I think you understand the issue. What is you problem now ?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I get multiple confirmation questions :).

Comment: Yes, sure because you call `Application.Exit` in the `OnClosing` mehtod. If this is the only problem, just dont do it ;)

Comment: But how am I supposed to close the application if the user presses yes then :O?

Comment: ?? if the user press yes, your app will close, but that has no effect on the "child" processes you have started. Sorry but i still dont know if you want to kill all child processes with you app or just your app that has started the childs

Comment: No no, see, an other function closes the other processes and I want this code to wait till that's done. The child processes are Java processes. NOTE: (It is a server that runs on Java and parse the output to a console in C#). Hope it is more clear now :)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10618/discussion-between-darkshadw-and-dknaack)